# Number of departures from n servers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, queueing-theory

Suppose There are n severs each of which has a service time exponentially distributed with mean m. What is the number of servers which complete their task till time t, nm m$\gg$t.

I am expecting it to have a Poisson distribution and the process to be a Poisson process  but can't seem to prove it.

Comment: You can get $\gg$ using `\gg`.

Comment: How can you compare a number of servers with a time?  Should it be $nm \gg t?$

Comment: @Ross Millikan Yes sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ denote the number of servers which have completed their task. We are interested in finding $P(Z=k), \; k=0,\ldots,n$.

Let $X_i$ denote the time taken by the $i^{th}$ server, where $X_i$ are  $\exp(1/m)$

$P(Z=0) = P(X_1>t, X_2>t, \ldots, X_n>t) = P(X_1>t)^n = (e^{-t/m})^n = e^{-nt/m}$

$P(Z=1) = {n \choose 1}e^{-t/m}(1-e^{-t/m})^{n-1}$

$P(Z=k) = {n \choose k}e^{-kt/m}(1-e^{-t/m})^{n-k}$

So $Z$ follows a binomial distribution with the parameters $(n, e^{-t/m})$

Comment: So $Z_t$ is not a poisson process?

Comment: @abc No, it is binomial. I edited the answer above. As a starter, the random variable of interest can only take values on $[0, n]$, which is a clue that the distribution cannot be Poisson.